# Openvpn issue with reconnection and multiple clients in the same NAT

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nat

I have a Openvpn server inside my home network allowing access from outside.

The setup is working but I still have two problems with it.

First when I loose VPN connection an try to reconnect immediately it fails. I have to wait few minutes until attempt to reconnect can succeed.
Second - if I try to connect with two clients at once (say laptop and mobile) that are behind the same NAT (say another residential network) then I can not connect at all - or I loose connection almost immediately.

How can I diagnose and resolve this issue? I have full access to the Openvpn server.

If it helps the servder uses `dev tun` and `proto udp` settings.

Comment: Can you update the question with what version OpenVPN you are running. And what it's running on? Maybe post the server config files (excluding sensitive information). I think you will get non-generic answers to this if you do!

Answer (score 0):

First, it probably takes time for the server to discover the connection has dropped and remove user from online list. Until then, user's attempts fail. You may find some timeout setting to reduce that period.

Second, OpenVPN (any some other protocols) cannot distinguish between multiple connections coming from behind the same IP address, as they take the IP as tunnel end-point. Change the protocol if feasible, or advise users.

Comment: Are there some open source alternatives to OpenVPN that would handle this NAT thing better? Take ip+port as tunnel end-point for example?

Comment: SSH port forwarding, HTTP Tunnel (source and binary available), ... But those are kinda expert friendly and not clean solutions for end user.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to DNS settings because your OpenVPN server is located in your home network.

Can you please upload your server log here?